# PHP Crop image, or just resize?

Tags: php, resize, crop

I'm working on a social networking website, and was wondering for when the user uploads there avatar picture (display pic), would it be better to have the image cropped to the size ( i'm using a 200 x 200 pixel area), or just have it uploaded ( i automatically scale it down to 600x800 ), then use the css to make it a 200 x 200? What would you recommend?

Comment: the former, the later does not change the file size

Comment: That's what I was using, but when I tested out an image, the face happened to be on the far right of the image, and it crops half of it out lol. xD

Comment: resize (server side) not crop, and tell the users. or install one of the fancy scripts where the user can select the crop area

Answer (score 0):

You can use gd library of PHP, for reference check [this site](http://www.icant.co.uk/articles/phpthumbnails/)